# rsync - copy contents of the directory only if a certain file doesn't exist

Tags: shell-script, shell, rsync, file-copy

We want to migrate contents of an old server to a new one but rather than coping everything, we want to exclude any directory that has a *.swf* file in it. We are aware of the `--exclude` flag but it will only exclude the file(s), not the parent directory (and it's contents), if there is a *.swf* file

If this cannot be done with rsync, is there a bash script we can use to copy files from one server to another, with this condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generate a list of directories which contain *.swf files, and then convert that list into an exclude file for rsync.

e.g.

```
find /path/to/topdir/ -iname '*.swf' -printf "%h\n" |
    sort -u |
    sed -e 's/^/- /; s:$:/**:' > rsync-exclude.txt
```

output will look something like this, which can be used with rsync's `--exclude-from=FILE` option:

```
- /path/to/topdir/directory1/**
- /path/to/topdir/directory2/**
- /path/to/topdir/directory3/**
- /path/to/topdir/directory5/subdir1/**
```

Note that rsync's include and exclude options can be difficult to master, they do not work quite like either globs or regular expressions.  You will  want to practice with `--dry-run` and `--verbose` first until you get the patterns exactly right.

Comment: I'm getting `sed: -e expression #1, char 16: unterminated \`s' command`. Any ideas why?

Comment: i must have somehow deleted the trailing `:` in the second sed expression.  fixed now.

Comment: If there are _.swf_ files in sub directories, they will be listed in the output file. But this is not a problem at all when using the text file in `--exclude` flag. Unfortunately still don't have enough reputation to upvote.